# Config Grid on Vue js using Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, gridview, grid, bootstrap-5

what's the correct way to configure grid on vue js using bootstrap??

currently I have this code: [CodeSandBox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-ully-kqkf49?file=/src/App.vue)

I configure on App the grid, like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
      <Header></Header>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 mt-5 mb-5">
      <Child></Child>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

my intention is for desktop the grid are going to be for Header: 3 grid and body: 9 grid, and for mobile header: 12 grid and body: 12 grid.

so currently I'm getting two issues, one is the body is taken 12 grid, you can see this picture:

[image]

and my second issue is about my dropdown menu profile, the menu is not showing correctly:

[image]

what's wrong??? what I'm doing wrong??